# django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: role "django" does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql, python-3.x, digital-ocean, ubuntu-16.04

I followed [this tutorial on Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-14-04) to install PostgreSQL 9.5 on an Ubuntu 16.04 server to use with Django 1.10.

Everything went smoothly, but I can't get my Django app to connect to the database (or so it seems). App and database are on the same server.

Here are some settings, configs and reports:

**The error I get:**

```
File "/home/mathieu/web/agencies/lib/python3.5/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  role "django" does not exist
```

**My Django project's database settings:**

```
DATABASES = {
'sqlite3': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')
},
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': 'agencies',
    'USER': 'django',
    'PASSWORD': '<password>',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
}}
```

**The hba_file**

```
postgres=# SHOW hba_file;
hba_file
--------------------------------------
/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf
```

**Its contents** (well, the relevant part anyway):

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

**Users and database in psql**

```
postgres=# \du
                               List of roles
Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
django    |                                                            | {}
postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}


postgres=# \l
                              List of databases
Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
agencies  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres         +
                                                            |  postgres=CTc/postgres+
                                                            |  django=CTc/postgres
postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
          |          |          |             |             |  postgres=CTc/postgres
template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
          |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

I followed the exact same steps on a VM (running Linux Mint, I should say) and all went fine and dandy...

I can't for the life of me figure out what's or where things are going wrong.

Comment: It's very strange because it should have given the message `password authentication failed for user "django"`, it would never have disclosed whether a user exists or not to someone who hasn't authenticated. It must be something outrageously obvious that we don't see. Could you show the full traceback?

Comment: Also, in your `settings.py`, try to change user "django" to "django1" and to "postgres" (with a wrong password); what error messages does it give in these cases?

Comment: When I set the USER setting to django1, I get a `django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  role "django1" does not exist` and when I set postgres as the user (with the wrong password), I'm getting a `django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "agencies" does not exist`.

Comment: I have pasted the full trace (user=django) here: http://pastebin.com/P3YL6dp5

Comment: It's almost certain it's connecting to a different PostgreSQL from the one you think. Try specifying a different `HOST`, such as a nonexistent host, and also "127.0.0.1", to see what happens.

Comment: The `migrate` command hangs when using `'HOST': '100.100.100.100'` and it gives a the error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "loclhost" to address: Name or service not known` when using `'loclhost'` (deliberately misspelled). When using `127.0.0.1`as the host, the error I get is `django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  role "django" does not exist` again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129604/discussion-between-antonis-christofides-and-laundromat).

Comment: After we investigated we found out there was a second PostgreSQL instance inside a forgotten Docker container. Not sure this is going to be helpful for other users, so maybe the question should be removed.

Comment: Or it could be closed as off-topic, which has this subcategory: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may see this error if you have postgres installed both locally (and running) and a docker container both trying to occupy the same port.

If the local instance starts first and is occupying a port that the docker image is also trying to use, docker won't necessarily tell you this.

When you try to run django or other `./manage.py` commands that need the database you'll see the same error because the app will not see the database you're looking for.

In this case, you can change the port on your locally installed postgres by stopping the server, clicking `Server Settings` and changing the port. You'll have to update `settings.py` on any apps you have depending on that old port.

In my experience, after doing this if you restart the docker db container you won't see this error anymore.

Comment: You're right :) See [my comment on another answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42435681/308204).

Comment: Ah, cool. I did not see that. Please mark the question answered / correct if you please! :)

Comment: This was my problem exactly, I looked all over to see why my database wasn't being made :-P thank you so much

Answer (score 6):

Refer the link [click here](http://www.kodefork.com/articles/2017/02/22/django-1-10-with-postgresql-9-5-ubuntu-16-04/). It is explained.

Your settings has

> 'USER': 'django',

But as error says that user doesn't exist , that means you have not created the user.

Just go into interactive session of psql and enter these commands.

```
CREATE DATABASE agencies;
CREATE USER django WITH PASSWORD 'password';
ALTER ROLE django SET client_encoding TO 'utf8'; 
ALTER ROLE django SET default_transaction_isolation TO 'read committed'; 
ALTER ROLE django SET timezone TO 'Asia/Kolkata';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE agencies TO django;
\q
```

then in settings.py

> 'PASSWORD': 'password',

password should not be enclosed inside < >.

Comment: Thanks, but the reason was a second postgresql database running in a Docker container. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40922239/django-db-utils-operationalerror-fatal-role-django-does-not-exist/42435681#comment69068025_40922239

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Docker, and it's listening to the 5432 port, you should kill other processes that are listening too.

To do this, type this command to see which processes are using port 5432:

```
$ lsof -i:5432
```

This will look like this:

```
COMMAND     PID           USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
com.docke 15178 andre.carvalho   86u  IPv6 0xb128ac87cd34cc69      0t0  TCP *:postgresql (LISTEN)
postgres  16670 andre.carvalho    7u  IPv6 0xb128ac87dc50c569      0t0  TCP localhost:postgresql (LISTEN)
postgres  16670 andre.carvalho    8u  IPv4 0xb128ac87d2378541      0t0  TCP localhost:postgresql (LISTEN)
```

After this, it's easy: Just kill the other process, with the command:

```
kill -9 16670
```

(Note that the process is identified by the PID.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add priveleges to user 'django':

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE agencies TO django;
```

Comment: I did add those privileges (as per the tutorial I referred to) but it's true that it does not seem to show in the \du overview. Should it?

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't lie. When it says "does not exist", it means "does not exist".

Comment: But why does the role `django` show up when I use `\du`?

Comment: Huh. I'm 100% sure I granted the privileges, but just to be sure I redid it. Now the access privileges has an entry for the database `agencies`. I'll update my question (because the error I get is still the same).